# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT with WHERE and other fields

Tags: mysql

I am trying to SELECT users with unique emails and with a certain Keyword also present. I tried using GROUP BY but that didn't seem to work.

How do I get the other fields? For example, here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT Email, FirstName, LastName, Picture FROM MyTable WHERE Keyword = '$Keyword'";
```

How would I get these 4 fields with the unique email?

Comment: I don't see why distinct would not work. Can you add sample data please.

Comment: When I add DISTINCT before the first EMAIL... then I get duplicate emails. If I just do DISTINCT EMAIL and no other fields then it works.. but I need the other info as well. FirstName, LastName and Picture.

Comment: DISTINCT is over all the selected columns - if any of the other 3 columns are different for the same email then you will get many of the same email. If that's the case which firstname/lastname/picture do want? If firstname/lastname/picture are unique then the emails are not even though they may appear so. Sample data please.

Comment: I found out that Picture is not DISTINCT. I got the data from Facebook Profile picture and it seems each one has a hash on it that is unique even tho it's the same picture. So how can I get only one picture from that person?

Comment: Each URL for each picture is UNIQUE so this is what is messing me up. So DISTINCT won't work. But I am thinking I can get an their FB ID and then later do another SELECT and just select their picture using that ID.. I think.

Answer (score 2):

1. `DISTINCT` will pick unique from all the selected columns:

```
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM MyTable WHERE Keyword = '$Keyword'";
```

2. `GROUP BY` will pick unique from all the group by columns
   If you want `FirstName, LastName, Picture` these fields as well then you can use this, as `FirstName, LastName, Picture they are not distinct then multiple details of a particular email will be omitted

```
    $sql = "SELECT Email, FirstName, LastName, Picture FROM MyTable 
            WHERE Keyword = '$Keyword' GROUP BY Email ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps group by with min might work for you

```
SELECT Email, FirstName, LastName, min(url)
FROM MyTable
group by Email, FirstName, LastName
```